# The accelerometer on different devices is somehow causing my app to crash

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash, accelerometer

This is a frustrating problem, because I can't easily debug my app for every different form factor. Two people have emailed me and said that 'the app crashes on tilt'. I've had one of the users with problems email me the output from the logcat when they run my app.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/vGVvix6A) is the output. I'm a bit new to Android development, so this is very cryptic to me and I'm not sure what it relates to in my actual code.

If it's helpful I can post any of my classes, or any information that would be useful.

EDIT: I could be wrong but my guess is that the output referring to the accelerometer starts around line 432 on the pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

They might be using tablets on which the default screen orientation is landscape and the origin is what would appear to be in the top-right corner of a phone.

Comment: In the code I force portrait orientation, but wouldn't the app crash before the accelerometer is used in that case?

Comment: It looks like it's screwing up on this:
08-01 13:56:16.632 E/SensorManager(26644): unregisterListener: com.sonaur.sonaur.AccelerometerManager$1@483115f8
Somehow, it looks like the sensor manager didn't get registered, did you create it like so:
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
         mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

Comment: Hm...here is the class I used for the accelerometer

http://pastebin.com/nDs0yzFR

Starting at line 109 I think the sensor manager is registered if the accelerometer is supported, though I could be wrong, I didn't write this code

Comment: The only two things i can think of are that:
1. you could be calling pause() and then not calling resume(). or
2. you are not calling isSupported() before runtime.

Comment: Well it has to be something specific to the devices that it is crashing on...it doesn't crash period on my Incredible, for example. I'll check out the things you mentioned